# Angularjs - Capture options selected from a dropdown list cascade

Tags: angularjs, capture, cascade

I have a select cascade, but I currently can't capture the first selected option, only the one of the second select.
I want to capture the two options selected by the user when the second selection is changed, so I could send this information to an asynchronous request.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ListDropdown($scope){
            $scope.ccvms={lista01:['1','3','5','7','9'],lista02:['2','4','6','8','10']}
            $scope.send=function(x){
                console.log(x)
            }
        } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ListDropdown">
        <select ng-model="nums" ng-options="ccvm for (ccvm, nums) in ccvms"></select>
        <select ng-disabled="!nums" ng-model="num" ng-options="num for num in nums" ng-change="send(num)"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "capture"? Do you want to send both `nums` array and selected `num`?

Comment: I want to send the array name and the item selected from this array. For example, I select lista02 and 8, so I send lista02 name and the number 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make the first select's model to be the key (rather than the value), and then use `obj[key]` as the source of the second `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-model="ccvm" 
        ng-options="ccvm as ccvm for (ccvm, nums) in ccvms"></select>

<select ng-model="num"
        ng-disabled="!ccvm" 
        ng-options="num for num in ccvms[ccvm]" 
        ng-change="send(num, ccvm)"></select>
```